# GridLayout not displaying correctly

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, grid-layout

I'm attempting to create an array of buttons and add them to a `GridLayout`, but for some reason, the grid does not get drawn correctly if I make it larger than about 5 by 5. If it's between about 7 by 7 and 10 by 10, the grid does not complete. If it's above that, the buttons are extremely wide and get displayed in a vertical column as opposed to a grid, and it extends off of the top and bottom of the screen.

My code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JButton[] btns = new JButton[49];

    GUI(String title){
        super(title);
        this.init();
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    void init() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(7, 7));
        for (int btnadder = 0; btnadder < 49; btnadder++) {
            btns[btnadder] = new JButton("");
            panel.add(btns[btnadder]);
            btns[btnadder].setBackground(Color.white);
        }
    this.add(panel);
    }
}
```

Comment: 7x7 = 49, but you're only filling in 25 spaces, there are going to left over spaces. GridLayout will fill each cell with component t based on the available space, so that each column and row is divided up equally, this is how its designed

Comment: Don't call `setSize(...)` but rather let the GUI set its own size based on the appropriate preferredSizes of its components and on the layout managers. Instead call `pack()` on the top level window after adding components and prior to setting visible. And avoid "magic" numbers like 25 and 49. Let Java calculate this number for you based on the rows and columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it is set between 7 and 10 are you changing

```
for (int btnadder = 0; btnadder < 25; btnadder++)
```

to account for the larger number of buttons?

Comment: Oh... I did forget to do this. However, the problem still remains for the larger grids. I'll edit that mistake now though.

Comment: Actually, I now realize that this was the main problem. I don't know why the other problem was happening before, but it seems to have stopped.

Comment: You shouldn't be using [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you set a layout manager for the `JFrame` that does not expand the components inside?

Other than this, I don't understand the question.  What is what you want?  49 buttons in a 7x7 arrangement?

Also, I notice you are not using `this.pack()` before `this.setVisible(true);`, and you are not setting the size of the buttons nor setting their label.  Try at least something like `new JButton(""+btnadder);`

I made these corrections, and I have a nice JFrame on my display right now.  Again, I don't know for sure what you expect.